# OpenCV4Android - Threshold Error

Tags: android, opencv, threshold

I have an image converted to CIELAB here. It works fine. However, when I conduct Thresholding using the Otsu method.

```
//convert to Greyscale
Imgproc.cvtColor(ImageMat, ImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2Lab);
//threshold
Imgproc.threshold(ImageMat,ImageMat, 1, 128,Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help but for Otsu's Method you pass 0, 255 and the method figures out the optimal see this for details. I have this example but it's in python: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Global_Thresholding_Adaptive_Thresholding_Otsus_Binarization_Segmentations.php

Comment: I got an answer on a similar question that worked for me. http://answers.opencv.org/question/57633/opencv4android-otsus-method-error/